# Why rounding error in bash?

Tags: bash, arithmetic-expressions, bc

```
5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7 = 17.9285714286
                     = 17.929
```

I want to get the exact value truncated to 3 decimal places, that is `17.929` by doing the following bash operation.

```
echo " scale = 3; 5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7 " | bc
```

But it gives me the value `17.928`.

```
$ echo " scale = 3; 5+50*3/20 + (10*9)/7 " | bc
17.928
```

What Can I do??

**N.B.:** This is a [Hackerrank challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---arithmetic-operations). Even it's not giving correct output in their console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `scale=3` in `bc`, you're not only specifying the number of decimal places in the output, you're limiting the number of decimal places that `bc` is using to do its calculations.

To get the correct output, use `printf` with `bc`:

```
$ printf '%.3f\n' "$(bc -l <<<'5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7')"
17.929
```

If the expression is inside a variable `$var`, replace the string in single quotes with `"$var"`.

Answer (score 4):

`bc` is ceiling the decimal value rather than rounding off. You can use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.3f\n", 5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7}'
17.929
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working! But, How to process a variable?? I mean, `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.3f\n", $a}'` is giving the output `0.000`.

Comment: You can use: `s='5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7'; awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.3f\n",'"$s"'}'` in that case.